# Why does R lubridate::duration datatype convert to character in spark using sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, lubridate, duration, sparklyr

I am converting my original R code to make it applicable in Spark using the `sparklyr` package. I use the `lubridate` package to calculate the duration in days between two dates. In R this results in the `duration` datatype which can then be transformed to a numeric datatype, as the following example will show.

```
# Load packages
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Create dataframe with start and end date
df <- tibble(start = ymd("20210101"), 
             end = ymd("20210105"))
df
---
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  start      end       
  <date>     <date>    
1 2021-01-01 2021-01-05
---

# Calculate duration and convert to numeric using R dataframe
df %>% 
  mutate(dur = end - start,
         dur_num = as.numeric(dur))
---
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  start      end        dur    dur_num
  <date>     <date>     <drtn>   <dbl>
1 2021-01-01 2021-01-05 4 days       4
---
```

Doing the exact same transformation on a Spark dataframe using `sparklyr` will generate an error, because the duration datatype automatically transforms into a string datatype. The code as well as the error is shown in the following example. Please ignore the change of date when transferring from local R to Spark which is caused by a difference in timezones.

```
## Connect to local Spark cluster
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "3.0")

# Copy dataframe to Spark
df_spark <- copy_to(sc, df)

# Calculate duration using Spark dataframe
df_spark %>% 
  mutate(dur = end - start)
---
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 3]
  start      end        dur   
  <date>     <date>     <chr> 
1 2020-12-31 2021-01-04 4 days
---

# Calculate duration and convert to numeric using Spark dataframe
df_spark %>% 
  mutate(dur = end - start,
         dur_num = as.numeric(dur))
---
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CAST(q01.`dur` AS DOUBLE)' due to data type 
mismatch: cannot cast interval to double; line 1 pos 30;
'Project [start#58, end#59, dur#280, cast(dur#280 as double) AS dur_num#281]
+- SubqueryAlias q01
   +- Project [start#58, end#59, subtractdates(end#59, start#58) AS dur#280]
      +- SubqueryAlias df
         +- LogicalRDD [start#58, end#59], false
---
```

Is it possible to use the `lubridate::duration` datatype in Spark using `sparklyr`? And if not, is there any way to bypass the conversion to string with the number of days as a double as a result? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use build in hive function to do this:

```
df_spark %>% 
  mutate(dur = datediff(end, start))

# Source: spark<?> [?? x 3]
  start      end          dur
  <date>     <date>     <int>
1 2021-01-01 2021-01-05     4
```

had it been a datetime object casting the datetime object to numeric before doing the diff will do e.g.

```
df <- tibble(start = ymd_hms("20210101 00:00:00"), 
             end = ymd_hms("20210105 00:00:00"))

df_spark <- copy_to(sc, df)

df_spark %>% 
  mutate(dur = (as.numeric(end) - as.numeric(start))/(3600*24))

# Source: spark<?> [?? x 3]
  start               end                   dur
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <dbl>
1 2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-01-05 00:00:00     4
```

Comment: Hi Kresten, thanks for your alternative approach. I used this alternative as well, but my question is focused on why this happens. the lubridate package is supposed to be supported, but apparently the lubridate duration datatype is not.